# Larmor precession with an oscillating field?

Tags: dipole-moment, infrared-radiation, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

With a non-polar molecule like CO2, presumably [Larmor precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession) doesn't apply.

However, CO2 has a mode of vibration that induces an oscillating dipole moment.

Could something similar to Larmor precession occur if a magnetic field were oscillated at the same frequency as the mode of vibration? So you could apply the IR frequency to the gas (e.g. with an IR laser at 667 cm$^{-1}$) and simultaneously apply an oscillating magnetic field to induce a far slower rotation of the CO2 molecules (I don't know what the rotational mode frequency would be, but likely <20GHz. My thought is that it would be the same order of magnitude as the rotating water molecules in microwave ovens).

Conceptually (as least to me), this would work because the dipole moment and the magnetic field both change signs in sync.

Has something like this been done before? Does this effect have a name? Could it be used to detect CO2?